# Iron-router nested routes with multiple parameters

Tags: routes, meteor, iron-router

I have two models: `sites` and `articles`. Each site can have multiple articles. I would like to view the article in the route like this: `/siteName/articleFriendlyTitleUrl`. At the moment I have helper method to make friendly urls like this:

```
getFriendlyUrl = function(urlString){
  urlString = urlString.toLowerCase();
  urlString = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-');
  return urlString;
}
```

And my `router.js` file:

```
this.route('showArticle', {
  path: '/article/:title'),
  layoutTemplate: 'artLayout',
  data: function(){
  viewData = {
    title: Articles.findOne({title: this.params.title}),
    site:  Sites.findOne({name: this.name})
  }
  return viewData;
});
```

Anyone have any idea how to implement this? I've also tried achieve this path:

```
/:siteName/:articleId
```

but without success - any suggestions?

Comment: I think you will need to store the "friendly title" that can form part of the URL in each article. Then look up the article by that name as given in your route parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend to save slug inside article document.
App can generate slug from title using Underscore.String.slugify function (https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) when user add/edit article.

Route with multiple params are valid:

```
this.route('showArticle', {
  path: '/:siteName/:articleSlug'),
  ...
  data: function(){

     viewData = {
       title: Articles.findOne({slug: this.params.articleSlug}).title,
       site:  Sites.findOne({name: this.params.siteName})
     }
     return viewData;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've solved this problem: I've followed suggestions and added `friendlyTitle` field to object from `Articles` collection that contains parsed article title (without special characters).

And this is my route:

```
this.route('showArticle', {
    path: '/:site/:friendlyTitle',
    layoutTemplate: 'artLayout',
    data: function(){
        return Articles.findOne({friendlyTitle: this.params.friendlyTitle});
    }
});
```

`:site` field contains name of the object from `Sites` collection that has this article assigned (when creating new article I can assing/publish it to/on the specific site).