# Supporting multiple parameters with nested properties in Meteor and Iron Router

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, routes, iron-router

Using Meteor and Iron Router, I've created dynamic page paths that use multiple parameters. However, if I attempt to access nested/child properties in my path, the route breaks. These posts were helpful but did not address child-properties:

[Iron-router nested routes with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620192/iron-router-nested-routes-with-multiple-parameters)

[meteor iron-router nested routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725081/meteor-iron-router-nested-routes)

### Iron Router

```
this.route('location',{
  path: '/properties/:foo/:_id',
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('properties', this.params._id);
  },
  action: function(){
    this.render('propertyPage', {
      data: function(){
        return Properties.findOne(this.params._id);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

### Markup (Works)

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'location' foo=bar }}">Click Me</a>
```

When attempting to reference a nested property in the markup, it breaks:

### Markup (NOT working)

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'location' foo=bar.nestedChild }}">Click Me</a>
```

I also tried it inside of the javascript, with no luck:

```
path: '/properties/:foo.nestedChild/:_id',
```

Is there a way to reference a nested property without breaking Iron Router?

### - - - Edit - - -

For a more practical example:

```
// data context from route action (Properties.findOne(this.params._id))
property = {
  _id: "3cu7B8b6K3EzCgYnQ"
  address: {
    city: 'Houston',
    state: 'TX',
    zip: 77006,
    lat: null,
    lng: null
  },
  images: ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png'],
  schools: [
    { grade:'elementary', name:'Haude', rating:4 },
    { grade:'middle', name:'Strauke', rating:5 },
    { grade:'high', name:'Klein', rating:3 },
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to build out a url schema like this:

```
path: '/properties/:address.city/:address.state/:address.zip/:_id'
```

or in the example's case:

```
"/properties/Houston/TX/77006/3cu7B8b6K3EzCgYnQ"
```

Comment: Would you please explain why you need a **nested property**.  It is not clear to me from the example you've provided.  Thanks.

Comment: The 'why' is because I'm working with a complex JSON schema inside of the Properties Collection. For example, I need to access nested properties of an object called 'address' which has a bunch of children like 'city, zip, state, etc.'

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems like you could look up the **_id** of an 'address' object, and then simply dereference their attributes as in **address.city, address.zip, etc.**.  I think I'm missing how they're nested. If you could provide a data sample, that might fill in a missing piece.

Comment: Hey Chip, I added a more practical example for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be done in iron-router often, from what I've gathered.  You might have some better insight after reviewing https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/337.  I would suggest simplifying it by looking up just the *_id*, or if that's too ugly, use a *:slug* parameter in your route to support something similar (e.g., **/properties/:slug** where **:slug** might be **Houston-TX-77006** or some variation.

Comment: Unfortunately for SEO reasons I have to implement it as I described. Thank you for the link, I'll post my findings here soon!

Comment: What about if you just create a route that looks like **/properties/:city/:state/:zip/:_id**. You can look up the document with the **_id** and then do a quick validation to see if it matches the individual route parameters passed in. If they don't match, you could just throw an error, but otherwise you could render a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's little too late, but somebody might benefit anyway. I solved it the following way:

Defining a nested path (BTW Defining paths this way is better for SEO)

```
 <a href="/user/{{owner.id}}/playlist/{{id}}"> Content </a>
```

Router

```
this.route('playlistItem', {
  path: '/user/:owner/playlist/:playlist',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    // You can get your params 
    var ownerId = this.params.owner
    var playlistId = this.params.playlist
    // execute some code
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your route, you need to fetch **:foo** from the params object if you want to use it:

```
var foo = this.params.foo;
```

Comment: Chip, in this example I'm attempting to access a nested property of foo:   
var foo = this.params.foo['nestedChild'] or var foo = this.params.foo.nestedChild